# NSUserDefaults and storing values

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsmutablearray, nsuserdefaults

Hi I am trying to store an array into NSUserDefaults but I am having troubles. The method accepts an NSDictionary which I will store into an array that i will store into NSUSerDefaults. The problem is when I make a mutableCopy it says its a dictionary and not of type NSMutable array? This method is the first time I would be calling NSUserDefaults so I am unsure why the error is happening? Here is the code thanks

```
+(void) getRecentPhoto:(NSDictionary *)recentPhoto{

NSUserDefaults* defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
 //stores it as a dictionary? error happens here
NSMutableArray* recentPhotos = [[defaults objectForKey:@"recentPhoto"] mutableCopy];
NSLog(@"%@", [recentPhotos class]);
if(!recentPhotos) recentPhotos = [NSMutableArray array];
BOOL copy = NO;

//these will crash the program
NSLog(@"%@", [[recentPhotos objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"id"]);
NSLog(@"%@", [recentPhoto objectForKey:@"id"]);

 //this checks if it has been stored before by using an id key
for(int i =0; i < [recentPhotos count]; i++){

    if ([[[recentPhotos objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"id"] isEqualToString:[recentPhoto objectForKey:@"id"]] ) {
        copy = YES;
    }
}
if(copy ==NO)
[recentPhotos addObject:recentPhoto];
[defaults setObject:recentPhoto forKey:@"recentPhoto"];
[defaults synchronize];


}
```

This is the error

```
 NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe the problem is, in the end of this method, you try to store `recentPhoto`, which is a dictionary, into user default instead of `recentPhotos`, the mutable array you want to store.

Actually, I think it will not crash at the first time this method is called since `recentPhoto` has not been stored in user default. But after that, it will.

Comment: but the method crashes when I do the first NSLog

Comment: Yes, it doesn't have an objectAtIndex: method, since what you get from the user default is a dictionary, not an array.

Comment: It's times like these when I wonder what code is behind some of the apps I use...